# Computing number of seconds/msecs in a window

Tags: r, time, diff

I have a dataset with 2 columns that I want to use to generate a 3rd. It's time-based data, and looks something like this:

```
   raw_timestamp_part_2 num_window 
1                788290         11
2                808298         11
3                820366         11
4                120339         12
5                196328         12
6                304277         12
7                368296         12
8                440390         12
9                 28311         13
10                56286         13
```

I want the new column to be milliseconds within the window. Thus, for a new window, the value in my new column should be 0, but otherwise is should be the difference between the current timestamp and the previous timestamp.

`diff(df$raw_timestamp_part_2)` gets me close, but it doesn't give me 0 for the first observation in a window.

Comment: How about `c(0,diff(df$raw_timestamp_part_2))`

Comment: That gets me a step closer, but it only addresses the first element, not the rest of the new windows. (But thanks-- I missed that originally!)

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question.  But, you got two answers, anyway.  A base R solution would be `with(df, ave(raw_timestamp_part_2, num_window, FUN=function(x) c(0, diff(x))))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution.  If the data is called `df` then you can do

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, num_window) %>%
    mutate(newCol = c(0, diff(raw_timestamp_part_2)))

#    raw_timestamp_part_2 num_window newCol
# 1                788290         11      0
# 2                808298         11  20008
# 3                820366         11  12068
# 4                120339         12      0
# 5                196328         12  75989
# 6                304277         12 107949
# 7                368296         12  64019
# 8                440390         12  72094
# 9                 28311         13      0
# 10                56286         13  27975
```

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `data.table`s for this type of operation:

```
library(data.table)
##
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[
  ,delta:=c(0,diff(raw_timestamp_part_2)),
  by=num_window]
##
R> dt
    raw_timestamp_part_2 num_window  delta
 1:               788290         11      0
 2:               808298         11  20008
 3:               820366         11  12068
 4:               120339         12      0
 5:               196328         12  75989
 6:               304277         12 107949
 7:               368296         12  64019
 8:               440390         12  72094
 9:                28311         13      0
10:                56286         13  27975
```

Comment: Thanks-- I'd accept both answers if possible. I'm going with the dplyr answer just so I don't have to go back and forth with data frames versus tables, but I'm glad to see this for future reference.